# Finding number of ints between doubles

Tags: java

Given two double values, return a count of the number of integers between those values (including those values). The second parameter will always be larger than the first parameter.

intsBetween(3.5, 4.5) → 1

intsBetween(2.9, 4.1) → 2

intsBetween(3.0, 4.0) → 2

```
int intsBetween(double num1, double num2) {
  num1 = Math.ceil(num1);
  num2 = Math.ceil(num2);
  int numBer = (int) (num2-num1);
  if (num2-num1 == 1 )
  numBer++;
  return numBer;
}
```

Not sure where I'm wrong.
[Results of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiQDh.png)

```
 From    To Expected Actual
  3.5   4.5        1      2
  2.9   4.1        2      2
  3.0   4.0        2      2
   .3    .9        0      0
165.0 170.0        6      5
  0.0   6.8        7      7
0.001 0.999        0      0
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as you can see in the results of my code

Comment: "num2 = Math.ceil(num2);" --> "num2 = Math.floor(num2);"

Comment: `if (num2-num1 == 1 )  numBer++;` - why?

Comment: As a first step describe how you would do this with pen and paper and then try that with pen and paper, then try converting those instructions to java. e.g. step one round both numbers up, step two subtract the first number from the second. step three if the result is one make the result two. step four return the result.  That is what your code is currently trying to do.

Comment: The real problem is that @Aditya Guhan feels `Math.ceil(165D)` should equal `165`, which makes a lot of intuitive sense, but is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was intrigued by the `IntStream` concept, so I decided to try it out. I used the following code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestIntsBetween {
  public static int intsBetweenStream(final double num1, final double num2) {
    int below = (int)Math.ceil(num1);
    int above = (int)Math.floor(num2);
    return (int)IntStream.range(below, above)
        .count() + 1;
  }

  public static int intsBetweenStreamCorrect(final double num1, final double num2) {
    int below = (int)Math.ceil(num1);
    int above = (int)Math.floor(num2);
    return below < above
        ?(int)IntStream.range(below, above).count() + 1
        : below == above
          ? 1
          : 0;
  }

  public static int intsBetween(final double num1, final double num2) {
    int below = (int)Math.ceil(num1);
    int above = (int)Math.floor(num2);
    return above - below + 1;
  }

  @Test
  public void try_3_5___4_5 () {
    int actual = intsBetween(3.5, 4.5);
    assertEquals(1, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void try_2_9___4_1 () {
    int actual = intsBetween(2.9, 4.1);
    assertEquals(2, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void try_3_0___4_0 () {
    int actual = intsBetween(3.0, 4.0);
    assertEquals(2, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void try_0_3___0_9 () {
    int actual = intsBetween(0.3, 0.9);
    assertEquals(0, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void try_165_0___170_0 () {
    int actual = intsBetween(165.0, 170.0);
    assertEquals(6, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void try_0_0___6_8 () {
    int actual = intsBetween(0.0, 6.8);
    assertEquals(7, actual);
  }

  @Test
  public void try_0_001___0_999 () {
    int actual = intsBetween(0.001, 0.999);
    assertEquals(0, actual);
  }
}
```

As expected, the simple approach, subtract the ceiling of the lower from the floor of the upper, then add 1, works like a charm.

The `IntStream` approach, however, fails a few of the tests, specifically the pairs (0.001, 0.999) and (0.3, 0.9). This is because the stream generates zero integers in each of those ranges, whereas the subtraction method produces -1.

This fault can be corrected as seen in `intsBetweenStreamCorrect`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the ceiling of the first number and the floor of the second number to get the proper range.

```
public class DoubleRange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleRange doubleRange = new DoubleRange();
        System.out.println(doubleRange.intsBetween(3.5D,  4.5D));
        System.out.println(doubleRange.intsBetween(165D,  170D));
    }

    public int intsBetween(double num1, double num2) {
        num1 = Math.ceil(num1);
        num2 = Math.floor(num2);
        return (int) num2 - (int) num1 + 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: There has been an extremely quickly downvoted and now deleted answer that proposed exactly that.

Comment: @GyroGearloose The deleted question kept the original bug, using ceiling for both ends of the range. It also used a `Stream`, which is inefficient and confusing. I didn't, and wouldn't, downvote it, but this is a different and better answer.

Comment: @erickson I saw an edit where the floor-bug was included and handled.

Comment: @GyroGearloose pity. I liked the concept. Inefficient? Sure, since this solution is simple subtraction. Confusing? Not if you are used to thinking in such terms.